# Why factor variable is not reordering in R

Tags: r

I am using example from this page: http://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/faq-how-to-order-the-factor-variables-in-ggplot2/  but the code does not seem to be working:

```
d <- data.frame(Team1=c("Cowboys", "Giants", "Eagles", "Redskins"), Win=c(20, 13, 9, 12))
d
     Team1 Win
1  Cowboys  20
2   Giants  13
3   Eagles   9
4 Redskins  12
> 
d$Team1
[1] Cowboys  Giants   Eagles   Redskins
Levels: Cowboys Eagles Giants Redskins
> 
> 
d$Team3 <- reorder(d$Team1, d$Win)
d
     Team1 Win    Team3
1  Cowboys  20  Cowboys
2   Giants  13   Giants
3   Eagles   9   Eagles
4 Redskins  12 Redskins
> 
> 
d$Team3
[1] Cowboys  Giants   Eagles   Redskins
Levels: Cowboys Eagles Giants Redskins
> 
> 
d[order(d$Team1),]
     Team1 Win    Team3
1  Cowboys  20  Cowboys
3   Eagles   9   Eagles
2   Giants  13   Giants
4 Redskins  12 Redskins
> 
d[order(d$Team3),]
     Team1 Win    Team3
1  Cowboys  20  Cowboys
3   Eagles   9   Eagles
2   Giants  13   Giants
4 Redskins  12 Redskins
>
```

The Team3 column is same as Team1 despite the reoder command. Where is the problem. Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

```
levels(d$Team1)
[1] "Cowboys"  "Eagles"   "Giants"   "Redskins"
> 
levels(d$Team3)
[1] "Cowboys"  "Eagles"   "Giants"   "Redskins"
>
```

Comment: When I run your code, I do not get the result for `d$Team3` that you're showing. I see levels reordered. You also seem to be mixing `order` (the sort order of the variable in the data.frame) and `reorder` (the `levels` that correspond to each integer value in the variable). Perhaps this is causing some confusion, as well.

Comment: I am using order to test if level has been reordered. I tried restarting R but the problem remains. I am using R.version 2.15.1 on Linux Debian Stable and version 3.1.0 windows.

Answer (score 0):

The function `reorder` changes the order of the levels, not the order of the values:

```
> levels(d$Team1)
[1] "Cowboys"  "Eagles"   "Giants"   "Redskins"
> levels(d$Team3)
[1] "Eagles"   "Redskins" "Giants"   "Cowboys"
```

Comment: I am getting same output. Please see my Edit.