# Ordering x-axis in ggplot in R

Tags: r

I am using following data & code:

```
ddf = structure(list(number = 1:20, words = structure(c(10L, 20L, 17L, 
6L, 5L, 13L, 11L, 1L, 8L, 15L, 3L, 18L, 16L, 7L, 4L, 14L, 12L, 
2L, 9L, 19L), .Label = c("eight", "eighteen", "eleven", "fifteen", 
"five", "four", "fourteen", "nine", "nineteen", "one", "seven", 
"seventeen", "six", "sixteen", "ten", "thirteen", "three", "twelve", 
"twenty", "two"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.34420683956705, 
0.612443619407713, 0.7042224498, 0.832921771565452, 0.351153316209093, 
0.622333734529093, 0.932609781855717, 0.584015318658203, 0.968014082405716, 
0.141673753270879, 0.787956288317218, 0.852732613682747, 0.411922389175743, 
0.781018695561215, 0.474310273537412, 0.701303839450702, 0.339094886090606, 
0.442493645008653, 0.941094532376155, 0.135925917653367)), .Names = c("number", 
"words", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")

 head(ddf)
  number words     value
1      1   one 0.3442068
2      2   two 0.6124436
3      3 three 0.7042224
4      4  four 0.8329218
5      5  five 0.3511533
6      6   six 0.6223337


ggplot(ddf)+geom_bar(aes(x=words, y=value), stat="identity")
```

[image]
However, I need to order the x-axis factors ('words') in proper numeric order ('one', 'two', 'three' etc on x-axis). How can I achieve this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to specify label order during factor creation

```
> lix = order(ddf$value)
> lvls = ddf$words[lix]
> ddf$words = factor(ddf$words, levels=lvls)
> ggplot(ddf) + geom_bar(aes(x=words, y=value), stat='identity')
>
```

[image: sorted barplot]

The above example orders the bars by the `value` column in the data table. If you need to order the bars according to the literal meaning of the labels, you will have to specify it manually:

```
> lvls = c('one', 'two', .....)
```

Comment: No. I want to order by words in numeric order: one, two, three, four etc.

Comment: @rnso see my edit. Also, you may want to edit your question to make it clearer

Comment: Edited my question. I do not want to manually enter 'one', 'two', 'three' etc. Can I use the numeber column (1,2,3,..) to do this?

Comment: then see jihoward's answer

Answer (score 2):

This reorders by the values in the number column.

```
library(ggplot2)
ddf$words <- reorder(ddf$words,ddf$number)
ggplot(ddf)+geom_bar(aes(x=words, y=value), stat="identity")
```

[image]

If you Google "reordering x axis in ggplot" you'll get about 100 hits that explain how to do this.

Comment: Above command is not altering my graph. Here also reorder command is not working on my system as in my other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981042/why-factor-variable-is-not-reordering-in-r

Comment: The code above reorders the factor `ddf$words` based on the values in `ddf$number`. If that's not what you are asking for, can you please explain it differently as an edit to your question.

Comment: For some reason, reorder function is not working on my system, as mentioned in my comment above. Is there any other method?